# Visual Studio 2017 y Chrome: ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY al iniciar un nuevo proyecto

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core, certificado-ssl

Acabo de descargarme el Visual Studio 2017 desde la página de Microsoft, y lo he instalado en una máquina con Windows 10 Profesional. He creado un proyecto nuevo de ASP.NET Core con la plantilla de Angular. Le he dado a ejecutar, y tras ello, Visual Studio me ha preguntado si quiero instalar un certificado generado por él para que funcione la depuración usando SSL. He aceptado, y al arrancar Chrome, éste ha contestado:

```
ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY
```

No sé a qué se debe. He buscado en internet y he probado varias cosas, como generar un nuevo certificado, etc. Pero nada.

Mi entorno es:

```txt
Visual Studio Professional 2017, 15.9.7    
Windows 10 Pro, 1709, compilation 16299.402
Chrome 72.0.3626.119
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Vale, he dado con la tecla. El problema es que IIS Express 10 usa HTTP 2 por defecto, pero éste a su vez tiene requisitos de seguridad más estrictos que el HTTP 1.1. Lo que he hecho ha sido desactivar HTTP 2, para ello, hay que meter estas claves en el registro:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters]
“EnableHttp2Tls”=dword:00000000
“EnableHttp2Cleartext”=dword:00000000
```

Espero que te sirva.